# golang with mongo db APIs Slow Response Time issue

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using golang as backend with mgo library. I have an API to get a slice of apprx. 45000 values from collection.

```
var listed[] string
err = getCollection.Find(bson.M{"emp_dept":"xyz"}).Sort("emp_name").Distinct("emp_name", &listed)
```

I am using Postman to test my APIs. when i hit the API from localhost then it take response time is in `ms` but when I test the API from server( we are using AWS `ec2` free verson), response time is in `seconds`. I tried using index on emp_dept and emp_name but it has no effect on response time.

Comment: Read up on profiling/benchmarking and identify where the time is being spent.

Comment: @D.SM can you give me some more information about this. I am new to golang and I have read profiling/benchmarking but I do not How to use it for golang and mongodb

Comment: @RajandeepKaur, have you indexed emp_dept on your AWSs MongoDB?
Is the response time on API calls without database calls significant slower, too?

Comment: @tobi.g yes I have indexed `emp_dept` but it has no effect on performance. My other APIs working good but this time I am fetching rich document aprox 45000 entries so response time on AWS ec2 server is more slower than localhost

Comment: Did you create mongo indices?